# How to setup header / alt. row / row style for MvcContrib Grid?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, grid, styles

I have got the following code.

How to setup **header / row / alt. row style** there?

```
@Html.Grid(Model.PagedList).Columns(                         
                        col =>
                        {
                            col.For(c => c.Name).Named("Name");
                          col.For(c => c.City).Named("City");
                          col.For(c => c.StateName).Named("State");
                          col.For(c => c.StartDateString).Named("Start Date");
                          col.For(c => c.EndDateString).Named("End Date");
                        }  ).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions).Attributes(@class => "grid")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
    table.grid {
        /*table style */
    }


    tr.gridrow {
        /*row style */
    }

    .grid tr th
    {
        /*header style */
    }

    .gridrow td {
        /*table data style in a row */
    }

    .gridrow_alternate td {
         /*table data style in an alternate row */
    }

    tr.gridrow_alternate {
        /* alternate row style */
    }
```